# An update to {} inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)

Tags: reactjs, testing

well I have a test in which I want to verify if a creation method works correctly what happens... I have this error, I cant use another libraries that I show.

```
Warning: An update to EventFormCreate inside a test was not
wrapped in act(...).

      When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

      act(() => {
        /* fire events that update state */
      });
      /* assert on the output */
```

and this other error:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0
```

Explain this is the test that I created and this

```
test('Submits from create event', async () => {
      //Assert--------------
      await wait(() => {
        //expect(submitCreateEvent).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(submitCreateEvent).toHaveBeenCalledWith(fakeEvent);
      });
});
```

here I create a interface IModal and use this for my mock I use formik for onSubmit and execute here my mock

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'date-fns';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { FormControlLabel } from '@material-ui/core';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import {
  KeyboardTimePicker,
  KeyboardDatePicker,
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
} from '@material-ui/pickers';
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { createEvent } from '../../services/events/api';
import Loading from './../../components/Loading';

const eventTypes = [
  {
    value: 'ONLINE',
    label: 'Online',
  },
  {
    value: 'PRESENTIAL',
    label: 'Presential',
  },
];

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    '& .MuiTextField-root': {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: '100%',
    },
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: '100%',
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));
interface FormValues {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  venue: string;
  date: Date;
  booking: boolean;
  typeEvent?: string;
  state?: string;
  url?: string;
}
interface IModal {
  setCloseModal: () => void;
  submitCreateEvent?: (credentials: FormValues) => void;
}
const EventFormCreate: React.FC<IModal> = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState<Date | null>(
    new Date('2020-01-30T21:11:54')
  );

  const handleDateChange = (date: Date | null) => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  };

  const [switchBooking, setSwitchBooking] = React.useState({
    Booking: false,
  });

  const handleBookingChange = (name: string) => (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    setSwitchBooking({ ...switchBooking, [name]: event.target.checked });
  };
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      title: '',
      description: '',
      venue: '',
      date: new Date(),
      booking: false,
      typeEvent: '',
      state: '',
      url: '',
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      title: Yup.string()
        .max(50, 'Deberia tener menos de 50 caracteres')
        .min(10, 'Deberia tener mas de 10 caracters')
        .required('Required'),
      description: Yup.string()
        .max(500, 'Deberia tener menos de 500 caracteres')
        .min(50, 'Deberia tener mas de 50 caracters')
        .required('Required'),
    }),
    onSubmit: values => {
      if (props.submitCreateEvent != undefined) {
        props.submitCreateEvent(values);
      }
      saveData((formValues: FormValues) => {
        if (props.submitCreateEvent != undefined) {
          props.submitCreateEvent(formValues);
        }
        saveData(formValues);
      });
    },
  });

  const saveData = async (values: any) => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const dataEvent = {
        title: values.title,
        description: values.description,
        venue: values.venue,
        date: selectedDate || new Date(),
        booking: switchBooking.Booking,
        typeEvent: values.typeEvent,
        state: 'PUBLISHED',
        url: values.url,
      };
      await createEvent(dataEvent);
      setIsLoading(false);
      alert('Evento Creado');
      props.setCloseModal();
    } catch (error) {
      alert('Evento No Creado ' + error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loading></Loading>
      ) : (
        <div
          style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', width: '80%', padding: '40px' }}
        >
          <form className={classes.root} onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <TextField
              error={formik.errors.title ? true : false}
              id="title"
              name="title"
              label="Titulo"
              variant="outlined"
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
              value={formik.values.title}
              helperText={formik.errors.title ? formik.errors.title : null}
            />
            <TextField
              error={formik.errors.description ? true : false}
              id="description"
              name="description"
              label="Descripciòn"
              variant="outlined"
              multiline
              rows="5"
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
              value={formik.values.description}
              helperText={
                formik.errors.description ? formik.errors.description : null
              }
            />
            <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
              <Grid container justify="space-around">
                <KeyboardDatePicker
                  disableToolbar
                  variant="dialog"
                  format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                  margin="normal"
                  id="date-picker-dialog"
                  label="Event Date"
                  value={selectedDate}
                  onChange={handleDateChange}
                  KeyboardButtonProps={{
                    'aria-label': 'change date',
                  }}
                />
                <KeyboardTimePicker
                  margin="normal"
                  variant="dialog"
                  id="time-picker"
                  label="Event Start Hour"
                  value={selectedDate}
                  onChange={handleDateChange}
                  KeyboardButtonProps={{
                    'aria-label': 'change time',
                  }}
                />
              </Grid>
            </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
            <TextField
              id="typeEvent"
              name="typeEvent"
              select
              label="Seleccionar Evento"
              onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
              value={formik.values.typeEvent}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              variant="outlined"
            >
              {eventTypes.map(option => (
                <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                  {option.label}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </TextField>
            {formik.values.typeEvent === 'PRESENTIAL' ? (
              <TextField
                id="venue"
                name="venue"
                label="Direccion"
                variant="outlined"
                onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                value={formik.values.venue}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
              />
            ) : null}
            <TextField
              id="url"
              name="url"
              label="Url"
              variant="outlined"
              onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
              value={formik.values.url}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Switch
                  id="booking"
                  name="booking"
                  color="primary"
                  size="medium"
                  checked={switchBooking.Booking}
                  onChange={handleBookingChange('Booking')}
                  value={formik.values.booking}
                />
              }
              label="Booking"
            />
            <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
              Crear evento
            </Button>
          </form>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default EventFormCreate;
```

this is the complet test subject

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
//import { createRender } from '@material-ui/core/test-utils';
import {
  cleanup,
  fireEvent,
  render,
  RenderResult,
  wait,
} from '@testing-library/react';
import EventFormCreate from './EventFormCreate';

let container: any;
const handleStCloseModal = jest.fn();

describe('Create Event Form Component', () => {
  describe('Submitting form', () => {
    //Arrange--------------
    // Set up variables accessible in tests
    //const shallow = createRender();
    let wrapper: RenderResult;
    let fakeEvent: {
      title: string;
      description: string;
      date: Date;
      booking: boolean;
      url?: string;
    };
    let titleNode = HTMLInputElement;
    let descriptionNode = HTMLInputElement;
    let dateNode = HTMLInputElement;
    let bookingNode = HTMLInputElement;
    let urlNode = HTMLInputElement;
    let createButtonNode = HTMLInputElement;
    let submitCreateEvent: () => void;
    afterEach(() => {
      cleanup;
      document.body.removeChild(container);
      container = null;
    });
    beforeEach(() => {
      submitCreateEvent = jest.fn();
      container = document.createElement('div');
      document.body.appendChild(container);

      const props = {
        handleStCloseModal,
        submitCreateEvent,
      };

      wrapper = render(
        <EventFormCreate
          setCloseModal={props.handleStCloseModal}
          submitCreateEvent={props.submitCreateEvent}
        />
      );

      fakeEvent = {
        title: 'Esto es un titulo de prueba',
        description:
          'esto es una descripcion de un evento que sera creado es solo de prueba y tiene al menos 500 caracteres de largo',
        date: new Date(),
        booking: true,
        url: 'www.localhost.com',
      };

      titleNode = wrapper.container.querySelector('#title') as HTMLInputElement;
      descriptionNode = wrapper.container.querySelector(
        '#description'
      ) as HTMLInputElement;
      bookingNode = wrapper.container.querySelector(
        '#booking'
      ) as HTMLInputElement;

      dateNode = wrapper.container.querySelector(
        '#date-picker-dialog'
      ) as HTMLInputElement;

      urlNode = wrapper.container.querySelector('#url') as HTMLInputElement;

      createButtonNode = wrapper.container.querySelector(
        'Button'
      ) as HTMLInputElement;

      //Act--------------
      // Change the input values
      fireEvent.change(titleNode, { target: { value: fakeEvent.title } });
      fireEvent.change(descriptionNode, {
        target: { value: fakeEvent.description },
      });
      fireEvent.change(dateNode, { target: { value: fakeEvent.date } });
      fireEvent.change(bookingNode, {
        target: { value: fakeEvent.booking },
      });
      fireEvent.change(urlNode, { target: { value: fakeEvent.url } });

      fireEvent.click(createButtonNode);
    });
    test('Is create event on document', () => {
      // This test passes
      // so fireEvent.click(loginButtonNode) does work
      act(() => {
        ReactDOM.render(
          <EventFormCreate setCloseModal={handleStCloseModal} />,
          container
        );
      });
      const form = container.querySelector('form');
      const submit = container.querySelector('Button');
      //Assert--------------
      expect(form).toBeInTheDocument();
      expect(submit).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    test('Submits from create event', async () => {
      act(() => {
        ReactDOM.render(
          <EventFormCreate
            setCloseModal={handleStCloseModal}
            submitCreateEvent={submitCreateEvent}
          />,
          container
        );
      });
      //Assert--------------
      await wait(() => {
        //expect(container.submitCreateEvent).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(container.submitCreateEvent).toHaveBeenCalledWith(fakeEvent);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: possible solution: https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/535#issuecomment-578698731